# Export to pdf: Double border appearing thick line where as in Excel it is appearing properly

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio 6.4* to create jrxml. I am using below code to create double line for text box.

```
<bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </box>
```

But double line border appearing as a solid thick line for pdf generated file but same code creates proper double line in Excel file.

The line at Excel output:

[image: Excel File Out put]

The same line at pdf:

[image: pdf file out put]

Comment: Can you post screen shots of two outputs, from Excel and pdf?

Comment: I have uploaded the out put file

Comment: @GulshadAnsari did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, after I changed the `Pen Width` to `1.25`, double line is able to be shown on pdf.

If `Pen width` is 0.5 or 0.75, double line is displayed as single line.